# E:The package libwinpr-handle0.1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, updates

I tried everything to fix this problem and nothing fixes it. It all started happening after I installed updates for Ubuntu and got a blue screen of death at reboot. Now I can't install any updates or packages or do anything because I get this error. Please help me figure out what's causing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And "sudo apt-get update" also doesn't work. It just says "Reading package lists... Done".

Comment: Please add all the new details as update to the question